# Ansible: Conditional task parameter

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to pass `ssl_ca` to `mysql_db` module only if `mysql_use_ssl` is defined. Is this possible using one task, like:

```
mysql_db: name=mydb state=import target=/tmp/mysql.sql login_host="mydbhost" login_user="root" login_password="password" {% if mysql_use_ssl %}ssl_ca=/path/to/cert.pem{% endif %}
```

?

This actual snippet does not work, result:

```
{"failed": true, "msg": "template error while templating string: Encountered unknown tag 'endif'.. String: /path/to/cert.pem{% endif %}"}
```

When moving the conditional as:

```
mysql_db: name=mydb state=import target=/tmp/mysql.sql login_host="mydbhost" login_user="root" login_password="password" ssl_ca="{% if mysql_use_ssl %}/path/to/cert.pem{% else %}none{% endif %}"
```

Then it "works" but `none` is not a supported parameter for turning off mysql ssl connection, so it does not turn off ssl.

Answer (score 15):

There is [omit](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters) keyword/variable for this:

```
mysql_db:
  name: mydb
  state: import
  target: /tmp/mysql.sql
  login_host: mydbhost
  login_user: root
  login_password: password
  ssl_ca: "{{ '/path/to/cert.pem' if mysql_use_ssl | default(false) else omit }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

starting from ansible v2.8, you can do ternary operator:

```
...
ssl_ca: "{{ (if mysql_use_ssl) | ternary('/path/to/cert.pem', false, omit) }}"
...
```